# Unable to send cookie via angular js http post to asmx web service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, cordova, cookies

I am writing a ionic cordova hybrid application. However, I am facing a problem which until I can solve, else I can't proceed.

**services.js:**

```
dataFactory.getListOfCases = function(){

    var req = {
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'http://'+IPAddress+'/DoorWS.asmx/GetList',
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
     },
     data: 'maxItems=1000'
    }

    return $http(req);
    };
```

**controller.js:**

```
dataFactory.getListOfCases().success(function(resp){
    console.log(resp); 
}).error(function(err){
    console.error('ERROR', err);
});
```

**cookie object:**

```
ObjectAccessLevel: 0  
Active: true  
AssociationDisplay: "admin"  
CreateBy: ".system."  
CreateTime: "/Date(1436165295956)/"  
Display: "admin"  
ID: "20150706_144815_6382141985"  
IPaddr: "192.168.2.82"  
Info: "DB Authentication"  
ReadCount: 0  
SessionID: "20150706_144815_6382141985"  
UpdateBy: ".system."  
UpdateTime: "/Date(1436165295956)/"  
UserAccessLevel: 5  
UserID: "admin"  
VersionNo: 0
```

So anyway, I am trying to do a http post to the asmx web service. The asmx web service only consumes a cookie object before it is able to give me JSON data.

Do let me know detailed instructions. Thank you.